# combine t-test results into a dataframe with broom

Tags: r, statistics, plyr, broom

I'm trying to repeatedly sample two vectors, `x` and `y`,  100 times and compute a t-test after each sample. I then want to combine the results into a dataframe using the `broom` package. My attempt at doing this is below. However, all I've managed to do is carry out 100 t-tests on the same two vectors.

```
library(plyr); library(broom)

x <- rnorm(10000, 3, 3)
y <- rnorm(10000, 5, 3)


x_sample <- sample(x, size = 20, replace = FALSE)
y_sample <- sample(y, size = 20, replace = FALSE)

ldply(1:100, function(x) tidy(t.test(x_sample, y_sample)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replicate` with `mapply`.  We replicate the `sample` for `n` times for 'x' and 'y', and do the `t.test` for the corresponding `list` elements using `mapply` and then `tidy` the output.

```
n <- 100
mapply(function(x,y) tidy(t.test(x,y)), 
       replicate(n, sample(x, size=20, replace=FALSE), simplify=FALSE), 
       replicate(n, sample(y, size=20, replace=FALSE), simplify=FALSE))
```